Formula to return 1 if all the cells in a range contain 'yes' otherwise return 0
I need a formula that will return a 1 if all cells in a range contain yes, or return 0`.
I can get it to return a 1 using =IF(L6:L15="YES",1) but after that I'm stuck.

Sorry, I am at work and did not realize my caps was still on

don't count YES, count the not YES

COUNTIF
=IF(COUNTIF(L6:L15,"<>YES"), 0, 1)


COUNTIF returns the count of cells in the range that do not contain "YES".
The IF function will interpret any non-zero number as TRUE, and value_if_true=0
IF will interpret zero as FALSE, and  value_if_false=1

COUNTIF variation
Dispenses with the IF function and instead converts the boolean value to a number with the the double unary operator -- or a calculation *1 saving a couple of characters.
=--(COUNTIF(L6:L15,"<>YES")=0)   // double unary operator

=(COUNTIF(L6:L15,"<>YES")=0)*1   // calculation approach


COUNTIF again returns the count of cells without "YES".
The result is compared to zero which returns TRUE if 0 was returned, or FALSE if a non-zero number was returned.
Convert the boolean TRUE/FALSE value to 1/0 using either:

The double unary (or double minus/double negative) operator
Using the boolean value in a calculation achieves the same thing e.g *1 or /1 or +0 etc..



SUM
This formula uses the double unary operator to convert boolean values to ones and zeros, and then SUM provides the count. It also leverages the fact that current versions of Excel (unlike Google Sheets) will often automatically create array formulas when a range is included in the formula.
=--(SUM(--(L6:L15<>"YES"))=0)   // double unary operator

=(SUM((L6:L15<>"YES")*1)=0)*1   // calculation approach


Excel returns an array of boolean values for L6:L15<>"YES" which are converted to an array of 1 and 0 using the double unary operator -- or a calculation *1
The sum of that array is compared to 0 which returns a boolean value that is then converted to a number using -- or *1

Function Support:  COUNTIF  IF  SUM

Thank you, Thank you, Thank you! That worked!

@PaulaJames see P.b's answer for the shortest solution: =--AND(L6:L15="Yes") or  =AND(L6:L15="Yes")*1

Or shorter: =--AND(L6:L15="Yes")
AND returns TRUE only if all are Yes else FALSE.
-- converts the boolean TRUE to 1 or FALSE to 0.

Nice!  Excel isn't my daily driver anymore. I do like the auto-array formula features for code brevity.  You win with this approach.
